# Can AddIns in MAF (System.AddIn) have constructor parameters?

Tags: .net, add-in, system.addin, maf

I need to pass configuration settings to an AddIn created using the Managed AddIn Framework (MAF, aka System.AddIn). Can a put a settings parameter in the AddIn's constructor?

Another option would be to create an Initialize() method, but then I have to remember to call it before doing any work with the AddIn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is to use Initalize() method, because the pipelines use the constructor parameters for passing contracts.

Answer (score 1):

I too use an Initialize() method in my add-ins. Indeed System.AddIn invokes the parameterless constructor of the add-in class.

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clraddins/archive/2007/06/28/behind-the-scenes-activation-pete-sheill.aspx) is an explanation of what goes on during the activation of an add-in. It is an old post but the activation process is still the same. You can also check the source code of the System.AddIn assembly from Microsoft's [Shared Source Initiative](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/). You can download the one with Product Name = .Net and Version = 4 for Framework 4, install it and then look for [AddInToken.cs](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.AddIn/System/Addin/Hosting/AddInToken.cs) (it will lead you to AddInActivator.cs).

Comment: Nice. Tks for the tip.